# Can template classes point to instances of one another?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have 2 template classes, each with a pointer to the other;

```
template <typename T>
class A;

template <typename T>
class B;

template <typename T>
class A
{
  B<A>* p;
};

template <typename T>
class B
{
  A<B>* p;
};
```

How can I now instantiate these classes? I cannot simply run `A<B>` because `B` is not a type (it's a template type).

The instances of `A` and `B` operate in separate threads and carry considerable state and functionality, so inheriting them from one another and duplicating their functionality in each class is not a feasible option.

How can I solve this problem and have these types hold pointers/references to each other?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. `A<int> x` works fine.

Comment: I'm genuinely curious about in what circumstances such a design is desirable

Comment: Note that you have injected name, so your members are in reality `B<A<T>>* p;` and `A<B<T>>* p;`

Comment: It's been observed that "template class" is a bad name, _precisely_ because it gives rise to misconceptions like these. `A` and `B` are **class templates**. That means they are templates that can be instantiated to create classes, but they're not classes themselves. `A<int>` is such an instantiation of the class template, and therefore a class.

Comment: @user1620443 I think it goes without saying that such a design is never desirable, it's just one that a series of unfortunate events land you in.

Comment: @melpomeme if I do that, what do I template `B` on - it gets nasty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I solve this problem and have these types hold pointers/references to each other?

It's tedious but you can do it.

```
template <typename T>
struct A;

template <typename T>
struct B;

template <typename T>
struct A
{
   A() : p(nullptr) {}
   A(B<A>* ptr) : p(ptr) {}
   B<A>* p;
};

template <typename T>
struct B
{
   B() : p(nullptr) {}
   B(A<B>* ptr) : p(ptr) {}
   A<B>* p;
};

int main()
{
    A<B<int>>* a2Ptr = new A<B<int>>();
    B<A<int>>* b2Ptr = new B<A<int>>();

    A<int>* a1Ptr = new A<int>(b2Ptr);
    B<int>* b1Ptr = new B<int>(a2Ptr);
}
```

You can build more levels of nesting but the objects with deepest level of nesting must have a `nullptr` member variable.

```
int main()
{
    // This is conceptual, pseudo code, not compilable code
    // with N levels of nesting.
    // Member variable p is nullptr
    A<B< ...A<int>> ...>* aNPtr = new A<B< ...A<int>> ...>();
    B<A< ...B<int>> ...>* bNPtr = new B<A< ...B<int>> ...>();

    // This is conceptual, pseudo code, not compilable code
    // with N-1 levels of nesting.
    // Member variable p is non-nullptr
    A<B< ...A<int>> ...>* aMPtr = new A<B< ...A<int>> ...>(bNPtr);
    B<A< ...B<int>> ...>* bMPtr = new B<A< ...B<int>> ...>(aNPtr);

    A<B<A<int>>>* a3Ptr = new A<B<A<int>>>(b4Ptr);
    B<A<B<int>>>* b3Ptr = new B<A<B<int>>>(a4Ptr);

    A<B<int>>* a2Ptr = new A<B<int>>(b3Ptr);
    B<A<int>>* b2Ptr = new B<A<int>>(a3Ptr);

    A<int>* a1Ptr = new A<int>(b2Ptr);
    B<int>* b1Ptr = new B<int>(a2Ptr);
}
```